# Allow external access to specific user in MariaDB 10.3

Tags: mariadb, privileges, forge

I'm trying to configure a limited external access to MariaDB 10.3

> What I want

The user can only access to a view from an external access but shouldn't be able to be connected as root even if he has the password.

> Initial configuration

Using the default [forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) configuration we start with theses users:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
 > use information_schema;
 > select * from user_privileges;
```

Full result: https://pastebin.com/kNNVUjrz

TLDR;

Two root users:

- `root` accessible from : [`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, `51.99.999.101`*, `%`]
- `forge` accessible from : [`51.99.999.101`*, `%`]

One weird user:

- `debian-sys-maint` accessible from : [`localhost`]

.* *This is obviously a fake public ip*

> Configuration I want

- `root` accessible from : [`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, `51.99.999.101`]
- `forge` accessible from : [`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, `51.99.999.101`]
- `dummyuser` accessible form : [`%`]

> The problem

When I remove the user `'forge'@'%'` but keep `'forge'@'localhost'`, the user (`dummyuser`) has no more privileges.

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dummyuser'@'%' (using password: YES)`

> Details of what I did

connected through SSH to the server

```
$ mysql -u forge -p
 > create database mydb;
 > create view mydb.v as select user();
 > create user dummyuser identified by 'password';
 > grant select on mydb.v to dummyuser;
 > select * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like '%dummyuser%';
```

- GRANTEE: `'dummyuser'@'%'`
- TABLE_CATALOG: `def`
- PRIVILEGE_TYPE: `USAGE`
- IS_GRANTABLE: `NO`

Connected through my local PC

```
$ mysql -u dummyuser -h 51.99.999.101 -p
 > select * from mydb.v;
```

Returns what we want: `dummyuser@adsl-178-xx-xxx-123.adslplus.ch`

But now when I delete the user `'forge'@'%'` through SSH *(with root this time)*:

**Important Note:** Doing this step before creating the dummyuser did not solve the problem.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
 > drop user 'forge'@'%';
 > create user 'forge'@'localhost' identified by 'passowrd';
 > grant all privileges on *.* to 'forge'@'localhost' with grant option;
 > flush privileges;
```

Here come the problem: When I logon with `dummyuser` and try again:

```
$ mysql -u dummyuser -h 51.99.999.101 -p
 > select * from mydb.v;
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dummyuser'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by finding out what rows exist in the grant tables.  It looks like you may have done such, but let's do it two steps:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

Then, for each of those, do (with `...` appropriately filled in):

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR '...'@'...'
```

Now take the `GRANT ... TO ...` statements that that produced, turn them into `REVOKE ... FROM ...` (and remove the password clause).

Run those `REVOKEs` plus any new `GRANTs` you need.  *But be sure that a typo does not lock you out.*  Stay connected while you connect elsewhere and check the results.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking for with this. https://pastebin.com/4gGYAaHf They do have the privileges to select. (`dummyuser2@%` as been created by `forge@localhost` after `forge@%` got deleted.) --- I'm assuming there's some sort of inheritance with `%` and the username. Re-creating the user `'forge'@'%'` with full privileges allow dummyuser to select.

Comment: @cbaconnier - not quite "inheritance", rather some cryptic order of checking the Grants to see which one applies.  Some notes:  `'%'` does not include `localhost`.  More specific (fewer %s) grants override others.  Example (with your grants):  Probably `root@'%'` (less specific) is allowed nothing, while `root@'51.99.999.101'` (more specific) is allowed everything.

Comment: I figured it out with your help. I will make an answer how was the final configuration. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @rick-james I got a working case.

I had to (re)create a user `'forge'@'%'` with the same restricted access than `'dummyuser'@'%'`.
`'forge'@'localhost'` keep is privileges `root`

```
> show grants for root@localhost;                                                                                                          
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****' WITH GRANT OPTION 
  GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION      

> show grants for forge@localhost;  
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'forge'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****' WITH GRANT OPTION                   

> show grants for 'forge'@'%';              
  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'forge'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****' 
  GRANT SELECT ON `mydb`.`v` TO 'forge'@'%'  

> show grants for 'dummyuser'@'%';
  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dummyuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****'   
  GRANT SELECT ON `mydb`.`v` TO 'dummyuser'@'%'
```

Now when I create `dummyuser3@%` with the user `forge@localhost` and grant him: `grant select on mydb.v to dummyuser3;` the dummyuser3 will be able to select the view.
In case a user get access to `forge@%`, because of the restriction, it will only be able to select the view. Which is an acceptable solution.

[Edit] It works with THIS scenario: `create view mydb.v as select user();`
  In a real world, my view is based on an another table. In that case, the user `'forge'@'%'` also needs the privilege to select on that table.
This is a less acceptable solution. But that's the only one I got.

**In definitive, the question is still open**